# How to not display values in the nodes or the links in SankeyDiagram using networkD3 in R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

In the sankeydiagram example below, is there anyway to hide the "Values" being shown in the diagram while hovering - both on the Nodes as well as the Links. Im basically using the sankey chart to show a stylised flow diagram, and I would like the Values not be shown to the user at all

```
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
              units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

To be clear, in the screenshot below,I would still like to see the Wind-Electricitygrid, but would like 289KWH not be displayed[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can generate any text you want to be displayed in the tooltips and add it to the `htmlwidgets` object, then use some custom JavaScript to set the tooltip text to it...

```
library(jsonlite)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

# generate the text you want to display
energy$links$name <-
  paste0(energy$nodes$name[energy$links$source + 1],
         " -> ", energy$nodes$name[energy$links$target + 1])

sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
              units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

# add the names back into the links data because sankeyNetwork strips it out
sn$x$links$name <- energy$links$name

# add onRender JavaScript to set the title to the value of 'name' for each link
sn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  sn,
  '
  function(el, x) {
  d3.selectAll(".link").select("title foreignObject body pre")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  }
  '
)

# display the result
sn
```

[image]